# How to fix this build issue in android?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, data-binding, android-databinding

i keep getting this build error, i cant get the generated binding object correctly in the Kotlin code

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
> Error: The processing instruction target matching "[xX][mM][lL]" is not allowed.
```

i've tried to invalidate, restart, clean the project but it didn't pay off

Answer (score 0):

if the clean and rebuild doesn't work.I think that downgrading your gradle version to 1.2.3.I hope it helps.